# Prometheus stddev of offsets

Tags: grafana, prometheus

How would I get the standard deviation for previous 3 '1w' offsets?

In this example it can be done by create new offset metrics at scrape time.

```
offset_rate1h{offset="1w"} =   rate1h offset 1w
offset_rate1h{offset="2w"} =   rate1h offset 2w
offset_rate1h{offset="3w"} =   rate1h offset 3w
```

Than do this:

```
stddev without (offset) (offset_rate1h)
```

How would you accomplish this without having to create new variables?

Comment: That should compose fine as there's only limitations when it comes to functions on range vectors. Is there more to this question?

Comment: This would require me to set these this new offset_rate1h values within prometheus correct?  I am trying to figure out how to do this at query time and not rely on prebuilt offset metrics.  I hope that makes sense.